# Adafruit Doesn't work with Multiprocessing

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multiprocessing, adafruit, adafruit-circuitpython

These error can be reproduce with any adafruit device.These example is for GPS.
I have tested several adafruit products, they are all great quality. However they all seems to present the same problem when use with the multiprocessing module. The script dose not run and throws a Segmentation fault (core dumped). The script runs with threading but not multiprocessing.

These does not works:

```
import time
import board
import adafruit_bno055
import threading
import multiprocessing

fpsFilt = 0
timeStamp = 0

i2c = board.I2C()
sensor = adafruit_bno055.BNO055_I2C(i2c)

def test():
    while True:
        print("Quaternion: {}".format(sensor.quaternion))

Gps = multiprocessing.Process(target=test)

Gps.start()
```

But these works:

```
import time
import board
import adafruit_bno055
import threading
import multiprocessing

fpsFilt = 0
timeStamp = 0

i2c = board.I2C()
sensor = adafruit_bno055.BNO055_I2C(i2c)

def test():
    while True:
        print("Quaternion: {}".format(sensor.quaternion))
   
Gps = threading.Thread(target=test)

Gps.start()
```

Is there any way to use an adafruit product with multiprocessing?Thanks.

Comment: You are initializing the device in your main Process, before you launch the subprocess.  Then you are attempting to use it in the subprocess.  I am not surprised that this does not work.  I highly doubt that this has anything to do with Adafruit - I wouldn't expect it to work on any operating system.  The same problem may not occur with threads if the device's functions are threadsafe.

Answer (score 1):

Try this program.  I have eliminated all the global variables, initialized the device entirely in the secondary Process, and protected the program's entry point with a test for `__main__`.  These are all standard practices when writing this type of program.

Otherwise it is the same code as your program.

```
import time
import board
import adafruit_bno055
import threading
import multiprocessing

def test():
    i2c = board.I2C()
    sensor = adafruit_bno055.BNO055_I2C(i2c)

    while True:
        print("Quaternion: {}".format(sensor.quaternion))

def main():
    Gps = multiprocessing.Process(target=test)
    Gps.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":    
    main()
    while True:
        time.sleep(1.0)
```

Comment: To be fair, the `if __name__...` clause is only required on Windows (or if the start method is "spawn"). If you are using unix then adding such a clause may break your code if it depends on copy-on-write

Comment: I run on Windows so I will take your word for this.  I wasn't aware that the test for `__main__` could break code, but good to know.